# Strange jackson ObjectMapper behavior

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm having a trouble with my Java application receiving Spotify API auth tokens and mapping them to POJO with Jackson.

Every time my app requests data from Spotify API, I start with getting a new access token from this link: https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials

and the answer is JSON, that looks like this:

```
{
    "access_token":"BQAJmzZOdh2egvWEOEwy4wv-VKdhTUc4eZYJrIfAibjWLR4MPfrbV6KBNIiomPwJKsQN-3vmrGmG7lOXFaI",
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "expires_in":3600,
    "scope":""
}
```

Every time I launch my app, the first time it works nice, but then it crashes with:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.slowedandthrowed.darkjazzbot.mapping.spotify.TokenRequest` (although at least 
one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('BQCcDMOKUiVPscDrrBH77b2QbN9FuqjAJHuM3_1QD39MO9L20XzXneZUlJeIyukBVhPpaCWnKWRjUdggaCM') at [Source: (String)"{"access_token":"BQCcDMOKUiVPscDrrBH77b2QbN9FuqjAJHuM3_1QD39MO9L20XzXneZUlJeIyukBVhPpaCWnKWRjUdggaCM","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"scope":""}"; line: 1, column: 17]
```

I kinda duct taped this problem by creating a new ObjectMapper every time I need to map access token JSON to POJO, but if it would be a production app, it would harm the performance, so I need to find out whats the problem in using one ObjectMapper instance for all the time.

I also tried to map this JSON to Map<String,String> instead of mapping it to `TokenRequest.class` and the result was the same, so I don't think that this is the reason why mapping fails.

```
private String requestAccessToken() throws IOException {
        TokenRequest tokenRequest = null;
        
        URL accessTokenUrl = new URL(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_LINK);
        
        HttpURLConnection tokenConnection = (HttpURLConnection) accessTokenUrl.openConnection();
        tokenConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authString);
        tokenConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        tokenConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        
        tokenConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(tokenConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(TOKEN_REQUEST_PARAMETERS);
        wr.flush();
        
        System.out.println("Wow! Posted!");
        
        InputStream inputStream = tokenConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

        
        StringBuilder inputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String input = null;
        
        while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) inputBuilder.append(input);
        
        
        System.out.println("================================= TOKEN INPUT ======================================");
        System.out.println(inputBuilder.toString());
        System.out.println("================================= TOKEN INPUT ======================================");

        
        tokenRequest = spotifyObjectMapper.readValue(inputBuilder.toString(), TokenRequest.class);
        

        inputStream.close();
        reader.close();
        tokenConnection.disconnect();
        
        return tokenRequest.getAccessToken();
    }
```

TokenRequest.java:

```
package com.slowedandthrowed.darkjazzbot.mapping.spotify;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "access_token",
        "token_type",
        "expires_in",
        "scope"
})
@JsonRootName("access_token")
public class TokenRequest {

    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    private String accessToken;
    @JsonProperty("token_type")
    private String tokenType;
    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    private Long expiresIn;
    @JsonProperty("scope")
    private String scope;

    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    @JsonProperty("token_type")
    public String getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    @JsonProperty("token_type")
    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    public Long getExpiresIn() {
        return expiresIn;
    }

    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    public void setExpiresIn(Long expiresIn) {
        this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
    }

    @JsonProperty("scope")
    public String getScope() {
        return scope;
    }

    @JsonProperty("scope")
    public void setScope(String scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `@JsonRootName`? Note also that you can add `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)` to the class and get rid of every other annotation dealing with properties.

Comment: It was just an attempt to fix the app behavior. My problem was with turning UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE on and forgetting about it, so I saw an exception about "expected access_token class name". Thank you. Now I removed excessive annotations, understood the mapping better, and fixed overall behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my program because i created the problems for myself.
I recieved different data thru different APIs and mapped it to a POJOs via single instance of Jackson ObjectMapper. Some JSON object contain data by themself:

```
{
"property1":value1,
"property2":value2
}
```

While other had single nested object with data inside:

```
{
"object":{"property1":value1,
"property2":value2
}}
```

So i decided to turn UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE to TRUE and then my object mapper changed its state so its behavior became different between my first and second attempt to recieve access token.